# Pandas cannot be imported into IPython

Tags: python, windows, pandas, python-2.7, ipython

I am running `Windows 7.0`, with `Python2.7`. I installed pandas before installing `ipython0.12.1`(stable).

When I run `import pandas` in `IPython.exe` I get the error message:

> No module named pandas

If I call IPython from the start menu, via cmd it doesn't automatically run in `C:\Python27` where pandas is located. Instead it runs in a different path `C:\Users\mycomputername\\.ipython`. (It seems unreasonable that ipython would not be able to detect that the pandas library exists on the machine).

That being said, I also cd into `C:\Python27\dist\ipython-0.12` folder to run `ipython.exe` from there, where the appropriate libraries i.e. `distribute-0.6.26` and `pyreadline-1.7.1` were installed.

I still receive that error message. Does anyone know if the order of installation is particular on Windows7?

Comment: Can you `import pandas` in a vanilla Python interpreter?

Answer (score 4):

Do you have multiple versions of Python? Something must be borked with your Python path. Have a look at sys.path:

```
import sys
for x in sys.path: print x
```

pandas should be installed in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pandas` or in an egg directory there. You can find out exactly where by firing up the regular python interpreter and doing

`import pandas
print pandas`

Not sure what could be wrong in IPython.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Much appreciated. In the vanilla interpreter-- after importing sys and printing x, I see: 

C:\windows\system32\python.zip
C:\Python27\dlls
C:\Python27\lib
C:\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\Python27\
C:\Python27\
C:\Python27\LIB\site-packages

I then print pandas and see: <module 'pandas' from C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.pyc'> as you said.

Think I should lean toward deleting everything and re-installing? 
Another thing I just remembered is that I once installed PyLab. I'm not sure if this is an issue...

Comment: I think the problem is that iPython appears to be in at *least 3* locations. Oh boy.:

C:\Python27\dist;
C:\Python27\EPD\Lib\site-packages;
C:\Python\dist\iPython-0.12\build;

Pandas is in *none* of these. In the EPD\lib\site-packages I already have the 'distribute' library. So I will try re-installing pandas again there. If you disagree, plse let me know. thx.

Comment: You might consider deleting everything (including in Windows' Add/Remove Programs) and starting with a fresh install of EPDFree and pandas from PyPI

Comment: That worked. I will need to add the QT (which requires sip). I downloaded both of them to C:\Python27. It's not clear to me how to build them. For instance, usually we have a setup.py: There are none in either sip or QT. Do they need to be placed in the Lib folder in EPDFree as well?

Comment: They should be installed automatically by the PyQt installer .exe from Riverbank Computing

Comment: I suspect it did not do so here.  Since for instance, when I run %pylab qt in either the shell or iP[y] notebook, it fails. In the shell it says: 'no module named sip'. (Will installing sip be the fix; does it need to be built in a specific directory?)

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to update to pandas 0.8+ in this existing iPython framework?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. So the reason on my end was because I had the multiple versions of Python. Since, I had the other system before using iPython the directory was calling the very first version on the Python.

**What to do:**

1) check if you have the right Python path

```
import sys  
for x in sys.path: print x
```

2) If not delete the other version, if you really do not need many versions of Python.

That solved my problem.